# Error in as.character(query) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: sql, r

I was trying to load some data from the oracle database, During the proceeding every line of code was fine until I try to run the last line:
`df<- sqlQuery(sql_connection,sql_statement,stringsAsFactors=0)`,
an error in the title occurred.

So here is the basic structure of my code:

```
require(RODBC)
require(lubridate)
require(stringr)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

#server for N2 purge attribute
target <- "xxxx"
user   <- "xxxx"
pass   <- "xxxx"


#print("Working on lot history...")


sql_string <- paste0("select
xxxx
from
xxxx
where
xxxx

")

sql_statement <- sprintf

#sql_statement <- sprintf(sql_string, BackDate, DidList[m])
sql_connection <- odbcConnect(dsn = target, uid = user, pwd = pass,believeNRows=FALSE)

df<- sqlQuery(sql_connection,sql_statement,stringsAsFactors=0)
```

since I'm new to R, I don't feel I can tell where is the cause of the error. If someone can help me out with this I'd be much appreciated it.

Comment: You call `sqlQuery` with `sql_statement` which you define as `sql_statement <- sprintf`. Therefore `sql_statement` is not a character but a function instead or a so-called `closure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, you assign the base function `sprintf` to `sql_statement`:

```r
sql_statement <- sprintf
```

You then pass it to `sqlQuery()` as the second argument (`query`):

```r
df<- sqlQuery(sql_connection,sql_statement,stringsAsFactors=0)
```

The function expects `query` to be a character, so you get the error that R can't coerce a 'closure' (essentially [another name for a function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures)) to a character.

I assume you were trying to imitate this commented-out line:

```r
#sql_statement <- sprintf(sql_string, BackDate, DidList[m])
```

But it's not necessary if all you want to do is run the query you just wrote. So if we just tidy up your code so `sql_string` is passed straight to `sqlQuery()`, it should work as intended, though I [can't actually test it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because we don't have access to your database:

```r
require(RODBC)
require(lubridate)
require(stringr)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

#server for N2 purge attribute
target <- "xxxx"
user   <- "xxxx"
pass   <- "xxxx"

#print("Working on lot history...")

sql_string <- paste0("select
xxxx
from
xxxx
where
xxxx
")

sql_connection <- odbcConnect(dsn = target, uid = user, pwd = pass,believeNRows=FALSE)
df<- sqlQuery(sql_connection,sql_string,stringsAsFactors=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation and quick fix. I test it on my DB and it worked perfectly fine!